# One-way folder sync between 2 computers with online comparison but offline transfer via external HDD

Tags: offline, backup, file-synchronization

in short: I am looking for a file sync software for Windows that enables me to sync multiple drives of a local Windows computer to another one at a remote location via internet and offline via an external HDD.

Background:
I want so sync / backup / copy my local home server to an offsite location not far away, but I am limited on my internet upload speed which makes transfers over the internet a time consuming process (I am dealing with 60TB+ of data). Most of the time it is fine to sync small and medium sized changes over the internet but I have to transfer a couple of TB once or twice a month. Driving to the remote location is a matter of minutes, so I am looking for a way to plug a USB drive into my home server, automatically copy all new and updated files and meta data about file renames, deletions etc. to that drive, drive to the remote location, plug the USB drive into that machine and have it automatically merge / sync. Both machines are 1:1 duplicates with 8 drives each. Ideally, I would like to have the choice to sync via internet or external HDD.

Any ideas?
Cheers